# Thesis Template on Share Latex :: Changing Size

Tags: fontsize, templates, sharelatex

I'm presently using a template on ShareLatex called "PhD Thesis of University of Liverpool".  I'm using the longtable package in it, but don't seem to be able to change the font size in it.  If anyone could help, I'd be extremely grateful.  It's difficult to include a MWE, as it's a big template.  A snippet of my table looks like this:

```
\vspace{10 mm} \begin{longtable}{Cp{2.0cm}Cp{2.0cm}Cp{2.0cm}Cp{2.0cm}} \hline
\centering\arraybackslash\textbf{Text no.} & \centering\arraybackslash\textbf{No. of witnesses} & \centering\arraybackslash\textbf{Date (y/m/d)} & \centering\arraybackslash\textbf{Dimensions (iku)} \\ \hline \endhead
138 & 2-4\textmd{\textnormal{\footnote{The text is broken and some text beyond line 19 of the reverse is lost.}}} & 1 & 0.0.3 \\
139 & 3 & 1 & [x] + 0.0.2 \\
142 & 3 & 3 &  \\
144 & 4\textmd{\textnormal{\footnote{All of the witnesses are divine witnesses.}}} & 3/01/01 &  \\
145 & 4 & 03/02/01 &  \\
\hline \end{longtable}
```

If I simply put, say, \footnotesize at the top of the table, it gets ignored.

Many thanks,

James.

Comment: Put it just before `longtable` and add a pair of braces around all the stuff. If you want all your longtables to be in `\footnotesize`, loading `etoolbox`and adding  `\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\footnotesize}` should work.

Comment: Great, thanks!  I haven't tried the "etoolbox" thing, but the braces did the job.

Comment: @Bernard Wanna make that an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Done. You're right, mentioning the `\AtBeginEnvironment` might be of interest for some new LaTeX users.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the font size in a particular (long) table, you only have to write, say `\footnotesize`, just *before* the table, and enclose the whole fontsize change + table within a pair of braces.

If you want to have a font size change for all long rables in your document, write the following lines in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\footnotesize}
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Padkoi :o)

Comment: What does it mean and which language is it?

Comment: It means ‘You're welcome’ in some kind of phonetic/sms French language (padkoi=pas de quoi).

Comment: Which language is it?